# Is it possible to exclude variables from SonarQube uncovered lines?

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, code-coverage, code-analysis

I have quite some variables defined in my code and I would like them not to be counted for uncovered lines in SonarQube Uncovered lines. Is it possible? Or is there any good way to easily write tests for these variables?
The code is in Javascript (React).

An example of variables code:

```
const DECIMALS = 3;

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    height: 250
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi. Are these defined in a separate file? If yes you can exclude that file from analysis (https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/). Other than that I don't know a way to exclude a piece of code from coverage analysis.

Comment: For questions regarding SonarQube you can also use: https://community.sonarsource.com/